# Call dataframe with index in a loop

Tags: r

I have some data frame data1, data2, data10.
I want to combine all those data frames by rows.

I tried using rbind in a loop but i can't call dataframe correctly in the loop.

```
tempo<-data.frame()

for(j in 1:10){

  tempo<-rbind(tempo,eval(parse(paste0("data",j))))

}
```

but that doesn't work. R doesn't know the dataframe that i want to call with command eval(parse)

Thank you

Comment: `do.call(rbind, mget(paste0("data", 1:10)))` ?

Comment: You should avoid having lots of `data.frames` in your `env`, read Gregor's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames